# How do i write the zipkin trace to a file in a format(json) that is supported by the zipkin ui?

Tags: node.js, json, trace, zipkin

I want to write the zipkin trace data from the recorder to a file using NodeJS in a format which zipkin ui supports so that i can import the file into the zipkin ui later and do analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Zipkin currently supports four types of backend storage to store spans in-memory, MySQl, ElasticSearch, Cassandra. Although for production it is recommended to use ES or Cassandra. The other two can be used for learning and understanding. Traces stored in the in-memory is ephemeral and won't be available after the restart.

In the zipkin UI there is an option to see the trace and download it, which can be used to view at a later point in time. If you still have further questions drop in to the zipkin [gitter](https://gitter.im/openzipkin/zipkin) channel.